# SSO jbpm 6.2 via CAS server 4.0.0?

Tags: single-sign-on, wildfly, cas, jbpm

I want to use SSO jbpm 6.2 via CAS server 4.0.0 (and cas is running on tomcat) but i don't know how to do it. I searched on google but i can't find how to config wildfly of jbpm 6.2 with CAS server.

Please help me, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I have no expirience with CAS but this tutorial helped me set up jbpm 6.1 with WSO2 Identity Manager.

http://riyazmsm.blogspot.mx/2014/05/jbpm-60-sso-integration-with-wso2.html

It might not be the same but this can put you on the right track since CAS can also handle SAML. Wildfly uses picketlink to handle security federation, reading the docs will be helpful on your journey.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i configued jbpm with cas but when i login via cas-login form i still get error "UT005023: Exception handling request to /kie-wb-6.2.0.Final-wildfly8/: java.lang.NullPointerException" and still stuck.